# Errors with webutilities in production

Tags: java, tomcat5.5

Today when I enabled webutilities in production has been received error messages like these:

> classe: com.googlecode.webutilities.servlets.JSCSSMergeServlet
>   linha: com.googlecode.webutilities.servlets.JSCSSMergeServlet.processResources(JSCSSMergeServlet.java:365)
>   thread: http-8443-Processor1240
>   Mensagem: Failed to flush out: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream@14fb7e73

and

> classe: com.googlecode.webutilities.servlets.JSCSSMergeServlet
>   linha: com.googlecode.webutilities.servlets.JSCSSMergeServlet.processResources(JSCSSMergeServlet.java:352)
>   thread: http-8443-Processor877
>   Mensagem: Error while reading resource : /jsp/js/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.js

I checked and this file exists. I am trying reproduce those errors but can't.

Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally reproduced those errors with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    URL url = new URL("/jsp/js/jquery-1.4.4.js");

    try {
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

        byte[] b = new byte[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < 100;i++) {
            b[i] = (byte) stream.read();
        }

        System.out.println(new String(b));

        stream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How that connection is closed I can ignore thoses errors...